# Why GCC disabling below options by default on "westmere" architecture eventhough "westmere" supports them

Tags: gcc

I want to compile my application by enabling `-march="westmere"` on RHEL5 with GCC. But when I query gcc with `gcc -march=westmere -Q --help=target` for what all options that will be enabled for this arch, all of below options disabled by default

```
  -maes                                                 [disabled]
  -mcx16                                               [disabled]
  -mfxsr                                                 [disabled]
  -mmmx                                              [disabled]
  -mno-sse4                                        [enabled]
  -mpclmul                                           [disabled]
  -mpopcnt                                          [disabled]
  -msahf                                                [disabled]
  -msse                                                  [disabled]
  -msse2                                               [disabled]
  -msse3                                               [disabled]
  -msse4                                               [disabled]
  -msse4.1                                            [disabled]
  -msse4.2                                            [disabled]
  -mssse3                                             [disabled]
```

If I look at GCC homepage, it says "westmere" does support all of the instructions sets above. If so why doesn't GCC enabling these options by default?

Any adverse impact on application if I enabled them in my app compilation?
As of now I am using these options on another architecture for e.g Sandybridge.
So wanted to know whether any impact if they get disabled on Westmere?

Comment: What gets printed is very misleading. It got better with gcc-6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Q` is a developer-only option, and it causes `--help=target` to print what is essentially internal information.  In this case, due to the way the target selection options are implemented, the sub-option settings do not reflect the values of the overall settings.

You can look at predefined preprocessor macros to determine what is actually enabled in the compiler.  Compare:

```
$ gcc -E -x c -dM /dev/null | grep SSE
#define __SSE2_MATH__ 1
#define __SSE_MATH__ 1
#define __SSE2__ 1
#define __SSE__ 1
```

To:

```
$ gcc -march=westmere -E -x c -dM /dev/null | grep SSE
#define __SSE4_1__ 1
#define __SSE4_2__ 1
#define __SSE2_MATH__ 1
#define __SSE_MATH__ 1
#define __SSE2__ 1
#define __SSSE3__ 1
#define __SSE__ 1
#define __SSE3__ 1
```

(Note that both system compilers in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 (`gcc` and `gcc44`) do not support `-march=westmere`.)

Comment: So if above commands shows similar output , then we can assume the options that are going to be enabled/disabled is same for both architectures? (Note : I am using gcc 4.9.1 on RHEL5)

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question.  If the corresponding `__*__` constant is included in the output, the compiler will potentially use these instructions, yes (and not just when using intrinsics, depending on the instruction subset, the compiler version, and the optimization level, of course).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to look whether any default options differ between various archs with -mrach in gcc is, by passing those archs explicitly to GCC with simple test program and record them. Later read the default options passed to them by using readelf.

gcc -frecord-gcc-switches -march=native Helloworld.cpp -o test

readelf -p .GCC.command.line test

gcc -frecord-gcc-switches -march=westmere Helloworld.cpp -o test

readelf -p .GCC.command.line test

On RHEL5 x86 with GCC 4.9.1 above commands showed a subtle difference what compiler passing as default options.
As I posted in my question, passing westmere to -march not passing all these flags by default.